# where does NTFS stores file attributes

Tags: windows, filesystems, metadata, ntfs, file-attributes

I'm currently developing a file system and doing some research on existing ones, and in the file system I have in mind I would like to add extra metadata (or file attributes) to files besides the ones generally stored by FS's like NTFS that stores for each file its filename, type, path, size, date of creation and modification, and the proprietary.

In NTFS in particular I found that the $MFT stores for each file attributes like the file's name in $FILENAME and its timestamps in $STANDARD_INFORMATION, but what about the rest of its attributes like its owner, location, size and type?

I just ask this in order to understand if its possible to complement a FS like NTFS with extra metadata about files, like I said before, but I can't seem to understand where it stores the metadata it already has...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The owner can be determined via the $SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR attribute. The location, I believe you mean path on the volume, can only be determined by parsing directories until you come across that particular file (the INDX blocks that make up the B*-Trees of the filesystem store references to file records in the MFT). File size can be determined accurately from the $DATA attribute.

The file type can only be determined either from the file's content (certain file formats have markers) or from the extension contained in the file name. The file system is agnostic when it comes to file types. If you were referring to file types as in files, directories, links etc, these can be determined from the file record itself.

As for adding extra metadata it would be unwise to add additional attributes that the NTFS driver doesn't recognize since you would have to write your own proprietary driver and distribute it. Machines that do not have that driver will see the drive as corrupt. You should also consider what happens when the attributes take more than the size of the file record (which is fixed in newer versions of NTFS and it's 1024 bytes, unlike old versions where the size of a record may vary).

A good idea to solve this problem and make the file system available to users that don't have your software or driver installed is to add named streams. You could use your own naming convention and store whatever you like and the NTFS driver will take care of the records for you even if they get outside the 1024 limit. The users that do not have the software installed can view that file system and won't know that those named streams exist since applications typically open the unnamed stream passed by the NTFS driver by default (unless otherwise specified).